# Can I mix C++ and Java in Apache Ignite compute?

Tags: java, c++, distributed-computing, ignite

As a pretty common use case, we have some legacy algos written in C++.  With Ignite compute, can we wrap the C++ code into ComputeFunc's, treat them as Runnable or Callable, and then invoke them from the Java side on a different (likely) node using ignite.compute(...)?

If possible, this seems to be a much elegant solution than calling C++ using Java Process.  Or, there is a solution in Ignite can address this case?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: If you think this is a dumb question, or Ignite doesn't support mixing nodes developed in different languages (no compatible at the binary level), just say so. Don't just give down ticks without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Ignite C++](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/compute-grid)? It allows to run compute jobs written in C++ if that's what you're looking for. You just need to make sure that you've configured everything properly (it's all in the docs) and connect to the cluster with a C++ node.

That said, if your algorithms are complex enough there is a good chance that calling them from Java via JNI will not bring any visible performance difference but it will be easier than configuring Ignite C++.